# ORDER BY price with $ sign and commas

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my database named "price" and it setup as varchar.  It contains dollar sign as well as commas.

The values in my database are like this:

$100,000
$625,005
$115,990
$2,450,000
$137,005

and I would like it to order it like this:

$100,000
$115,990
$137,005
$625,005
$2,450,000

I tried  ORDER BY 0+price and ORDER BY ABS(price) but they just outputted in the order it was in the database.  Is there anyway to order this while keeping the field varchar

Comment: **Never - ever** store this kind of information in the same field. Either you specify the currency in an field and use it in your code to display the dollar sign - or you don't have it at all.

Comment: OMG! While there are semantic arguments about using floats vs integer values where there is no explicit currency type, using a varchar field is just silly!

Answer (score 9):

If at all possible, change your database to hold those values in a `int`, `float` or `decimal` field, depending on how much precision you need. Add the `$` and all other formatting when outputting the values.

Everything else is just duct-taping around a bad database structure. It's not impossible, but it should be the very last resort when there is absolutely no way to change the database.

Comment: The suggestion here is sound, however it does not provide an answer to the question being asked "Is there anyway to order this while keeping the field varchar"

Answer (score 2):

Fully agreeing with the above posts regarding the database design, there is a bad way anyways:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(price,',',''),'$','') as cleanPrice FROM Table ORDER BY cleanPrice
```

The query has to do the replacements on every single row and therefore might become very slow..

Answer (score 1):

Honestly you should really store these as int's and format them in PHP when you bring them out of the database, that way it's easier to work with the data and you can manipulate them as INT's.

When you pull them out you can use numeric_format to auto-add the comma's and then just add a $ infront of the price.

If you are storing multiple types of price's you can store a Currency Type in the DB too; which in this case would be USD.

Comment: The suggestion here is sound, however it does not provide an answer to the question being asked "Is there anyway to order this while keeping the field varchar"

Answer (score 1):

I did this in Oracle quickly, so it might not work in MySQL...if not, I'm sorry.  I'm only selecting the prices

```
select price
from table
order by (cast(substr(replace( replace('price', ',', ''), '"', '' ), 2, length(replace( replace('price', ',', ''), '"', '' ))-1) as int)
```

Comment: But yes, the ugliness of this query is why you should save numbers as a number data-type, and just use a formatting function to display it as money if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any way of changing the DB structure you can add a computed column to the table for sorting purposes.

Unfortunately, mysql does not support computed columns, so after you create the new column you would need to add triggers (on UPDATEs and INSERTs) to compute the value for every inserted/changed row on the table.

In your trigger you would use REPLACE(REPLACE(price,'$',''),',','') for the value of the new column.

You could also create a view that has this logic in it and select from that.

The mysql documenation for creating triggers is located [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

The mysql documenation for using views is located [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html)

Comment: +1 for the nicest workaround. It might be nice to have some links on how to get started building a trigger though.

Comment: @Pekka, thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my answer with the links to the documenation